# How To play mp3 files from one activity to another activity

Tags: android

I have two MP3 files saved in Raw folder...i have set these files in one Dialog Box. 
using below code:

```
 final int audio = this.getResources().getIdentifier("audio", "raw",this.getPackageName()); 
    int loveme= this.getResources().getIdentifier("loveme", "raw", this.getPackageName()); 
    final int [] songlist={audio,loveme};
```

now user select one song from List. and i want to play that selected song to another Activity
Please help me :(
Thanks And Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do it is pass that raw id with the activity and get it in the second activity..

Put this code in ActivityA class at time of selecting the mp3:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedMp3",SELECTED_MP3_INT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in onCreate() of ActivityB:

```
int mp3 = getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedMp3",DEFAULT_MP3_INT);
// PUT YOUR CODE TO PLAY SONG..
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: i want to pass mp3 from  arraylist..final int [] songlist={audio,loveme};

Comment: yes then you can get the position when item is clicked and then you can easily access by `songlist[selectedPosition]` and pass it to next activity using intent;

Comment: my app stooped working and says resourceid not found i did what u say  Intent intent = new Intent(SongListDialogextends.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedMp3",songlist[position]);                  startActivity(intent);                                            in next activity Intent intent=new Intent(SongListDialogextends.this,MainActivity.class);        int mp3 = getIntent().getIntExtra("selectedMp3",0);   
mps=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), mp3);
mps.start();:

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
  Intent nextAct =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
nextAct.putExtra("id",audio);
startActivity(nextAct);
```

And in the next activity get the song id as :

```
int identify=Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("id"));
```